# How do I migrate new MySQL database structure from dev to production website using the command line?

Tags: php, mysql, unix

I have two website environments (separate servers, Media Temple DVs): Dev and Production.

We started building the site on Production, then got a Dev server, so I originally moved the Production database to Dev using commands like this:

```
$ mysqldump -a -u USERNAME -p DATABASE > OUTPUT.mysql
$ gzip OUTPUT.mysql
```

Then I created the Dev server website and database, moved OUTPUT.mysql over and set up the MySQL environment on Dev for importing:

```
$ mysql -u USERNAME -p DATABASE

set up environment for large data import: 
mysql> set global net_buffer_length=1000000; 
mysql> set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000;
mysql> exit
```

And imported both data and schema to Dev with these commands:

```
$ gunzip -f OUTPUT.mysql.gz
$ mysql -u USERNAME -p TARGET_DATABASE_NAME < OUTPUT.sql
```

Now I've made changes to the structure of the Dev MySQL database, such as adding/deleting fields in existing tables, and adding tables, and I'd like to migrate my changes to Production.

How do I migrate just the updated structure from the Dev database and import into Production using the command line, similar to what I did originally, but without overwriting the live data? (All of my live data is on Production, so there is no need to bring data over from Dev.)

The database has become too large to do this with phpMyAdmin (besides, the command line seems quicker and easier to work with). It would be nice to stay away from third party tools or open source software for what seems like it should be a simple process that I can throw into a script. Or am I going about it wrong and there is something better I'm missing?

**UPDATE**: So, based on the below answers and additional reading, I ended up writing a PHP script that examines both the live database and my local database (that includes some changes) and compares the differences between the tables.

The script finds which tables are missing from the live database vs. local using the MySQL "SHOW TABLES" function on both databases and comparing. For these tables that are missing I used SHOW CREATE TABLE to get the MySQL statements for creating the tables.

Similarly, the script finds which columns are missing by using SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table on every table in each database. This MySQL command returns the column names and attributes, so I could then build ALTER TABLE statements automatically for columns that were missing.

Finally, the PHP script outputs everything as an SQL script for creating and altering the tables, which I ran in phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to produce some SQL statements to upgrade the structure of the database.

At the very least, you can use `mysqldump` to dump both databases *with no data*, just the structure, and use `diff` to see what has changed. That way you can include the `create table` statements for new tables, and write `alter table` statements for those tables that changed, to upgrade them.

Maybe there's a free script somewhere that can generate those `alter table` commands, it certainly sounds like a fun little project.

Alternatively, you can rename the old tables, import the development database, again without data, and insert the data from the old tables into the new tables by an

```
insert into mytable (col1, col2) select (col1, col2) from oldmytable;
```

where "col1, col2" etc. are the columns from the old table.

Again, the database can be queried for what columns each table has so you can easily write a script to generate these insert statements.

For the second approach the database will have to go offline for a little while (or a long while, depending on the size of the db).

Answer (score 4):

You have two choices:

1. Manually examine each table and determine what `ALTER` commands to execute to makes the same changes to production as you made to the dev environment
2. Use mysqldump to back up all the data in the production server, and tell it to skip the DROP/CREATE TABLE statements (look through --help for the command line option). Then dump the schema only from the dev server, import it to the production server, and import your backup to get the rows back in. This requires that you have not removed any columns.

In the future, you'll want to start keeping track of your schema changes. Modern ORMs like Doctrine, ActiveRecord have something called "migrations" that help you manage these and apply them to a database by keeping track of the schema version.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid if you don't want to erase the production data that's going to be painful.

- One tool you can use is the [mysql workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/). Create a EER schema by reverse engineering your development database and try to synchronize with your production server. You have to review all the queries mysql-workbench will do because it can be dangerous. I advice you to do a backup before starting anything.
- Second posibility is you to compare every tables and write some `ALTER table` queries for each different tables, like when you have removed/changed/added some fields to that table.

I think you should start some DB migrations tools for next time, like [rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/). If you don't want to use a tool your should create some SQL scripts with all your alter so you can upgrade the DB scheme easily. Also mysql workbench is quiet nice to do those kind of tasks but still a bit buggy.