# MySQL structure migration

Tags: mysql, data-migration

I have two separate environments - **staging** and **production**.
As of right now, **both databases are absolutely identical**, including data.

The structure of the **staging database** always changes during development - new tables, new fields, new changes.

I'm having difficulties with the **transfer** of staging DB **to production**.

I would like to migrate only the structural changes, without any data, when I deploy a new version to production.

Has somebody ran into similar problem? How can I make this process less painful?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447880/how-do-i-migrate-new-mysql-database-structure-from-dev-to-production-website-usi

Comment: You should execute the same alter table statements in production than in your stating DB.

Comment: Sorry. Did not find the duplicate. Seems like this is what I am looking for. Unfortunately, there is no any convenient way to do it.

Comment: For future changes, you should be using migration scripts to deploy all changes, rather than running commands in an ad hoc way on staging until you get what you want. Then when you are ready to deploy, just run the exact same scripts on production. See https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/using-migration-scripts-in-database-deployments/