# MySQL: How to migrate database structure from dev to stage environment with PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am doing constant upgrades to my clients website - and most upgrades include changes to the database structure.

Currently every time I change the structure, I build a seed file and run it when we go to the staging environment.

This is very time consuming and I can only assume there is a better way. Looking through PhpMyAdmin, there is a way to export just the database structure, but when I import this into my staging database it doesn't update the structure.

I tried following this thread, but I can't get anything to work: [How do I migrate new MySQL database structure from dev to production website using the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447880/how-do-i-migrate-new-mysql-database-structure-from-dev-to-production-website-usi)

Is there a way to quickly dump database structure changes from one database table to another without changing the data?

Comment: you can't dump "changes", but you can dump the structure of a table/db. mysql doesn't have any kind of revision control.

Comment: @MarcB I would like to dump just the structure of the table, but make it update the current table. So if a new column was added, it would add that column to the old table.